# Drawing an elevation profile between two markers in Maps API V2

Tags: android, api, maps, google-maps-markers

I'm a novice so I apologize in advance if my code and/or understanding is simplistic. I am attempting to build an app that allows me to select different markers and show not only the distance to the selected marker from my current location, but an elevation profile as well. I saw something similar to this in a Google Labs option for Maps where it allowed you to draw a line between two points and then it would give you a graph that showed the elevations between those two points. I've tried to find some answers here, but it seems nobody is really talking about this at all so I thought I'd ask. The code I'm currently using to give me the distance is:

```
  if (marker.equals(windy)) 
  {
      //handle click here
      WINDYINFO.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    

      float[] results = new float[1];
      Location.distanceBetween(myPosition.latitude, myPosition.longitude,
                      WDY.latitude, WDY.longitude, results);
      TextView distanceView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.windydistance);
      results[0] *= 0.000621371192;
      distanceView.setText(String.valueOf(results[0]));
  }
```

myPosition will always be my location according to GPS, and WDY is the elevation for the windy marker. How would I go about doing what I mentioned above, here, so that I can take the data and display it in my activity?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Evelation API from Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/). Take a look at the chart at the bottom of this page.

Comment: Is this something I can do in Android? All of this appears to be in Python and for use on the web, not so much android, unless I'm supposed to do this through a webview which I'd prefer to avoid here.

Comment: @J.S.Optional Of course you can do it natively in Android. Doing a simple webservice API call with `HttpURLConnection` or your favourite REST client library.

Comment: I'll have to learn more about doing that. Like I said, novice.

Comment: I can't seem to find any android code examples out there for this. Do you know of any that you could share that would work with my code?